# Django AngularJS JSONResponse view in rendering json output

Tags: python, django, angularjs, jsonresponse

i am developing one of my site with the python django where i have been using angularjs in one of my page where i have given the user option to search (specific request). Here is my model..

```
class Request(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    sub_category = models.ForeignKey(SubCategory)
```

In my views I am returning through the following code:

```
def some(code, x):
    exec code
    return x

def search_request(request):
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    term = request.GET.get('term')
    i = 0

    terms = "x = Request.objects.filter("
    for t in term.split(" "):
        i=i+1
        if(len(term.split(" "))>i):
            terms = terms +"Q(name__icontains='"+t+"')|"
        else:
            terms = terms +"Q(name__icontains='"+t+"'))"

    junk = compile(terms,'<string>', 'exec')

    spit = Request.objects.filter(name__icontains=term)
    requests = some(junk,spit)

    output = HttpResponse()
    output['values']=[{'requests':r,'category':r.category,'subcategory':r.sub_category} for r in requests]
    return JSONResponse(output['values'])
```

In my HTML code when I return using AngularJS:

```
$scope.search = function(){
    $scope.results = $http.get("{% url 'search-requests-show' %}?term="+$scope.term).then(
        function(result){
            return result.data;
        }
    );
}
```

The result on the HTML Output comes as in {[{results}]}:

```
"[{'category': <Category: The New Category>, 'requests': <Request: Need a Table>, 'subcategory': <SubCategory: Testsdfsdfsad>}]"
```

The problem is that I am not being able to access using results.category because the output is in "string", so the ng-repeat="result in results" brings the result as

```
[ { ' c a .....
```

I am probably doing something wrong in view. If anybody has any suggestion then please answer.

Comment: Off-topic, but is `compile` really necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JSONResponse` is probably using standard python json encoder, which doesn't really encode the object for you, instead it outputs a string representation (`repr`) of it, hence the `<Category: The New Category>` output.

You might need to use some external serializer class to handle django objects, like:

http://web.archive.org/web/20120414135953/http://www.traddicts.org/webdevelopment/flexible-and-simple-json-serialization-for-django

If not, you should then normalize object into simple python types inside the view (dict, list, string.., the kind that json module has no problem encoding). So instead doing:

```
'category':r.category
```

you could do:

```
'category': {'name': r.category.name}
```

Also as a sidenote: using `exec` is **super bad idea**. Don't use it in production!

Answer (score 0):

You should return json strings for Angular:

```
import json
def resource_view(request):
    # something to do here
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(your_dictionary))
```

for better usage i recommend [djangorestframework](http://django-rest-framework.org/).

Off Topic:

```
$http.get("{% url 'search-requests-show' %}?term="+$scope.term);
```

you can pass 'param' object:

```
$http.get("{% url 'search-requests-show' %}", {param : {term:$scope.term}});
```